# Merge Validation fails when running with Code Coverage when doing unit test through cloudtest

Tags: unit-testing, cloud, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, azure-powershell

We are trying to run Code Coverage tests using cloud test and it fails with the below exception:
***System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.***

The Tests pass if we run without the code coverage, but when code coverage is enabled it fails with the above error.

Things tried:
We tried running the code by adding : **[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1, SkipVerificationInFullTrust = true)] in the AssemblyInfo.cs** files, but did not help.

Could someone help shed some light why this might be happening or any fix for this?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set True in runsettings for the vstest task and enable the code coverage check box. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019)

```
<UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
```

The fix is present in the version of the vstest task greater than 2.153.0.

vstestplatform version needs to be greater than 16.1 (anything greater than 16.0.2 also works)

You can  check https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/pull/1997 for more details.

You can use the the combination of:

- Latest Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.2 (doesn't work with 12.0.1)
- Latest stable Test platform: 16.2 (should be >16.0.2)
- Latest VSTest task 2.156.2 (should be >2.153.0)

Here is a [ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/1950) with the same issue you can refer to.

Comment: Thank you Perry, would it be possible to point where the versions, JSON, Test Platform and VSTest task can be checked? also the question is for the Cloudtest for code coverage.

Comment: You can check the versions from the log, for example [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KscLo.png).